# how to add pagging here using html

Tags: html, css

How to Add Page Number in this html style for view page number like "page 1 out of page 1".

i want at the buttom of page after covert pdf to view like this:

"page 1 out of page 1"

anyone can help to do this style in html css here.
ThankYou for Your Trying.Please help me with this.

```
const html = `<html>

  <body>



 
  <style>
  div {
    text-align: center; 
  }
  c{
    text-align: right;
  }

  @page {
    size: landscape;
  }

    .demo {
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        padding:5px;
    
    }
    .demo th {
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        padding:5px;
        background:#F0F0F0;
    }
    .demo td {
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        padding:5px;
    text-align: center;
    }
</style>




<div>
<img src="https://www.comdelta.com.my/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Logo.jpeg" 
alt="Comdelta Technologies Sdn. Bhd" 
width="200" height="100"/>
</div>

</html>

  </body>`;
```

Comment: Your code seems incomplete. We need more context to help you.

Comment: const generatePdf = async () => {

  const file = await printToFileAsync({

      html: html,

      base64: false,

  });

  await shareAsync(file.uri);

}                                                                                                                                                                          and for the return i just using a button to click for pdf ....so basically i just want in my pdf page at the buttom the page number.

Comment: Add this to your question not as comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var pageNumber = 1
var totalPageNumber = 5
const html =`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <style>
          div {
            text-align: center;
          }
          c {
            text-align: right;
          }

          @page {
            size: landscape;
          }

          .demo {
            border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 5px;
          }
          .demo th {
            border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
            padding: 5px;
            background: #f0f0f0;
          }
          .demo td {
            border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
          }
          .pagenumber-bottom {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 10px;
            right: 10px;
          }
        </style>

        <div>
          <img
            src="https://www.comdelta.com.my/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Logo.jpeg"
            alt="Comdelta Technologies Sdn. Bhd"
            width="200"
            height="100"
          />
          <div class="pagenumber-bottom">
            page ${pageNumber} of ${totalPageNumber}
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>`
```

In the above code the class `pagenumber-bottom` writes in the bottom right corner of the page. You can change CSS property `bottom` and `right` to change the poistioning.

Comment: Yeah it's working but it's constant i mean i have more than one page but it's not counting for all document. can you help me with this.

Comment: one more thing -:) here my page landscape is not working.....is there anything missing or what is the issues if know anybody....

Comment: @AkashGhosh I have change the code above for dynamic page numbers. About the landscape thing not working I'm not too sure.

Comment: yes please help me with that dynamic page number please.

Comment: @AkashGhosh I have already changed the code snippet above for dynamic pages. You just have to change the `pageNumber` and `totalPageNumber` variables at the top of code snippet.